# react-native fails to run iOS with node:internal ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION

Tags: node.js, react-native

After updating my react-native application to `0.72.6` running `react-native run-ios` fails with the following error.
I cannot figure out what the source problem is. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
myproject/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/abseil/absl/meta/type_traits.h:301:36: builtin __has_trivial_destructor is deprecated; use __is_trivially_destructible instead [-Wdeprecated-builtins]

    : std::integral_constant<bool, __has_trivial_destructor(T) &&
                   ^

node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Error: Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Trygghetsmobilen.xcworkspace.".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

I have tried react-native `0.71.13` with node versions `16` and `18` and the same error occurs.  Also, there is no unhandled promise in the code of the project

The dev environment info is

```
System:
  OS: macOS 14.0
  CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
  Memory: 1.71 GB / 32.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 16.17.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 3.6.4
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 8.15.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.02.13.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods: Not Found
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.0
      - iOS 17.0
      - macOS 14.0
      - tvOS 17.0
      - watchOS 10.0
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
  Xcode:
    version: 15.0/15A240d
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 11.0.15
    path: /Users/amir/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.7.5
    path: /Users/amir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.6
    wanted: 0.72.6
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `cd ios/ && pod deintegrate`
2. Remove the Podfile.lock in ios/
3. `pod install`
4. Then run again `npx react-native run-ios`